# Ubuntu 19.10 suspend issue(first two times successful)

Tags: suspend

I have problem on the suspend feature on my ubuntu 19.10. I am using Dell Latitude 5490, normal intel graphic card. 
Scenario 1:
My problem is I could do pm-suspend two times successfully and wake up also successfully. At the third time issuing pm-suspend command, the laptop didn't really go to suspend. LED is two yellow and one white blinking. I have to force shutdown by pressing power button very long time. I have tried many solutions, but none of them work, could any one share some experience/knowledge, thanks.
Scenario 2:
Update on this issue, tried to issue pm-suspend command, first two times, works fine. The third time when I issue the pm-suspend, the computer didn't really suspend, the led on the power button is on and after a while, it get rebooted, anyone have any idea? Thanks.
Thanks in advanced for your help.

Comment: anyone experience the same issue? Am I the only one?

Comment: I installed arch linux in another laptop(same model dell latitude 5490), also have some issue on suspend, does it mean linux suspend feature doesn't work well on at least Dell latitude 5490?